# "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames": A feature, bug, or malware?

Tags: google-chrome, security, malware, google-maps, frame

friends . . .

I've been using Chrome for so long, and just recently receive a popup saying "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames" on a number of sites; it shows the loaded page with white bezel-like borders along the edges.

Also, just recently, Chrome starts to behave weirdly, particularly when I open Google Maps: For a brief moment before the page loads, sometimes, it shows a blank page with a "sad document" icon in the middle, *with the same white frame "bezel" along the edges like when the "For security reasons . . ." notification comes up*.

Both "For security reasons . . ." and Google Maps "sad icon" screenshots are attached.

Please help.

[Framing is not allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4qX4.png)
[Sad Document Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su2sq.png)

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  This is a feature to prevent malware, or more precisely to prevent others from leaching off the sites reputation by embedding its content in another site.

Comment: @davidgo I was a bit curious if this is normal, or someone is trying to do harmful things on my computer. I've been using Chrome for long, but this thing started to appear just a couple of days ago. I'm not sure if this is a feature added through a Chrome update or someone injected malware into the system and harvests whatever information I type or click on any pages after that. A friend of mine (who we worship as the god of IT here at our office) claimed that maybe someone put a malware that creates a layer over the original page to function as a keylogger, but I can't just believe it.

Comment: When I go to the site, I don't get those messages (but I am using a different platform).  I'm not sure your friend is corect, but its not impossible.   I do note that the actual site is http, not https, so it is possible to inject stuff into it.  Also, when I loaded it without an add blocker, the advertising almost gouged my eyes out, so its entirely possible something was amis.

Comment: @davidgo That's why I'm confused: I never had this kind of problem before, until just recently. I visit mangaka even since 2018, but the "For security reasons" notification appeared around 2 weeks ago as far as I remember.

EDIT: Also, about the https thing: I visited www.blastwave-comic.com/, and Chrome says it's not secure (meaning, no https, right?). But there's no "For security reasons" thing.